# Runtime error, sorting function without using .sort

Tags: python

I am supposed to write the sorting function. Define
a function sort list that takes in a list and returns a list sorted in ascending order.
(4 marks)
Note: your code should make use of the insert list function defined earlier.
With my previous defined variables:

```
def search(x , seq):
    for i in seq:
        if x > max(seq):
            return len(seq)
        elif x < min(seq):
            return 0
    return search(x, seq[:-1])


def insert_tup(x, tup):
    searchtuple = search(x, tup)
    ontheleft = tup[:searchtuple]
    ontheright = tup[ searchtuple:]
    altogether = ontheleft + (x,) + ontheright
    return altogether

def insert_list(x, lst):
    A = search(x, lst)
    lst.insert(A, x)
return lst
```

I did a trial

```
def sort_list(lst):
    result = []
    for i in lst:
        result += [i]
    return insert_list(result[0], lst)
```

But i keep getting Runtime error where
    File "", line 7, in search
    return search(x, seq[:-1])

The output is desired to be

```
sort_list([5, 1, 9]) 
[1, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Can't you just cheat and do `def sort_list(l): return sorted(l)`?

Comment: It'll be marked by the tutors so it's difficult. hahahaah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recursively calling the search() method and never breaking out of this loop. I expect this is raising a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` exception.

Python has a recursion limit to protect against infinite recursion. FYI you can modify the recursion limit via [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) - but this is not something you should be doing.

Instead you can fix this by re-writing your algorithm iteratively.

I also suggest you read the [Python sorting wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting), as this demonstrates the pythonic way to sort things with the built in `sorted()` function and the list method `sort()`. You don't need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You need a base case for the recursion. Something like:

```
if len(seq)==1:
    return seq
```

Otherwise it calls itself forever. And the result is the error that you see.